# When defining the probability generating function(pgf), why do we restrict ourselves to discrete random variable?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

When defining the probability generating function (pgf), why do we put the restriction of discreteness on our random variable? Replacing summation by integration, we could try to generalize it for continuous random variables as well, and derive the respective pdf. We don't do this! Why not?

Comment: The generalization exists and is called [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29).

Comment: Also try moment-generating function